# What does this variable coefficient represent of electric field of dipole?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, dipole

[image]

$V:=\text{potential at point P}$

$V=\frac{2Qd\cos(\theta)}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}r^{2}}$

$E_{r}=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$

$E_{\theta}=-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta}$

The problem for me is that $E_{\theta}$

What does $\frac{1}{r}$ represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric field is related to the potential in the following way $$\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla}V.$$

In spherical coordinates, the gradient is $$\vec{\nabla}=\hat{u}_r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\hat{u}_\theta\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+\hat{u}_\phi\frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi},$$ so the $E_\theta$ component is

$$E_\theta=-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$r$ is a distance that is defined on your sketch. $\dfrac{1}{r}$ is its reciprocal.